# Spring - Thymeleaf iteration

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Suppose I want to obtain a structure like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <!-- Item -->
    <li class="item">
      <span class="more no-select" data-target=".item1">+</span>
      <span class="right"></span>
    </li>

    <!-- Children -->
    <li class="item1 hidden nojs">
      <span class="spacing"></span>
      <a href="mylink">My link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item1 hidden nojs">
      <span class="spacing"></span>
      <a href="mylink">My link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item1 hidden nojs">
      <span class="spacing"></span>
      <a href="mylink">My link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically each `item` has [0 ... n] `children`.

To obtain this structure using Thymeleaf I'd start by defining the main items as follow:

```
<li th:each="item : ${items}">
  <span class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">+</span>
  <span class="right"></span>
</li>
```

But then, being that `item` is limited in scope, how do I cycle through its `item.children`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to move the `th:each` to a higher level, so that you can also add the children after each `li` element. The `th:block` element should be handy because it itself creates no HTML element but can carry any Thymeleaf attributes.

The outline of the solution should be as follows:

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${items}">
    <!-- Item -->
    <li class="item">
        item content ...
    </li>
    <!-- Children -->
    <li th:each="child : ${item.children}" class="item1 hidden nojs">
        child content ...
    </li>
</th:block>
```

Comment: For reference, this is the link to the documentation for th:block http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag

Answer (score 3):

```
<li th:each="item : ${items}">
    <span th:each="child : ${item.children}" class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">+</span>
</li>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

---

I see you updated your question.
OK, then the answer is: no, you cannot do it this way, and you aren't supposed to. `<li>` is supposed to contain homogeneous data. Sometimes html coders do it the way you're showing to achieve certain results in the representation, but it's a hack and not semantically correct, and should be avoided.

You need to reconsider the design to do something like this:

```
    <li th:each="item : ${items}">
        <span class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">+</span>
        <span th:each="child : ${item.children}" class="some class" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">child related things</span>
    </li>
```

And the representation should be then managed by css.

---

**Hacky way**
I was to slow adding this...
I don't think it's a way to go, but in comments you mentioned that Thymeleaf is the only engine that cannot do that which didn't seem very cool to me :)
Although I vote against it, you might look at the `th:block` and make use of it:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag which actually can achieve this (not tested, please try it yourself):

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${items}">
    <li th:text="item1">
          <span class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">+</span>
    </li>
    <li th:each="child : ${item.children}">
        <span class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${child.id}">child related things</span>
    </li>
</th:block>
```

Comment: Nope. Look at the code structure I posted. I need the second part of the li(s), which are the item's children. You just reposted what I already wrote.

Comment: @LppEdd This is a little vague then. Could you post an example of result you want to get?

Comment: @LppEdd I didn't repost what you wrote. I have an iteration through item.children in my code.

Comment: Look at the updated source code in my question. You should understand better now. Specifically look at the two comments in HTML

Comment: I need to style items and children in the same way, which would not be possible (or at least, it will add complexity) with a li > span solution. Do I have to resort to pure JSP?

Comment: I mean, at this point I have to say Thymeleaf is the only engine which cannot do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in thymeleaf pretty easily.

```
<th:block th:each="item : ${items}">
    <li>
        <span class="more no-select" th:attr="data-target='.' + ${item.id}">+</span>
        <span class="right"></span>
    </li>

    <li th:each="child : ${item.children}" class="item1 hidden nojs">
        <span class="spacing"></span>
        <a href="mylink">My link</a>
    </li>
</th:block>
```

Comment: Both yours and obecker solutions are correct. I will give the answer to obecker cause it posted first (by a couple of seconds hahaha). Thank you!